# Import Anaconda module error ... "no module named"

Tags: pandas

I have installed Anaconda and everything seems to run smoothly but when I run the script:

import pandas as pd

it gives me the error:

"No module named pandas"

However when run the import statement in the shell, the program imports just fine. I am wondering if this has something to do with the directory since I am using a work computer that has multiple drives. I was able to run the import statement on my home computer just fine. The same error seems to occur when importing any of the Anaconda modules.

It would be great to have someone's thoughts as to how to fix this problem or if I can perform some checks on seeing where the problem lies.

Thanks so much!`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can try :-

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pandas
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Else on the terminal, try `pip install jupyter` that may solve your problem. You need to first check if anaconda is working properly, how your libraries are not imported. Better reinstall with latest version and try again if above doesn't work. I hope it helps.